# Maximum RTCDataChannels in Chrome

Tags: c++, google-chrome, webrtc

[Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel) states that a single RTCPeerConnection can handle "in theory" 65,534 data channels yet states that the limit will vary browser to browser. I haven't been able to find documentation as to the maximum RTCDataChannels allowed in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome announces [1024 outgoing streams](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/webrtc/media/sctp/sctptransport.cc?l=213&rcl=46671402fff3375666cccdcca7bd0f6ff222ff60) and uses the usrsctp default of 2048 incoming streams.

For comparison, Firefox announces [256 outgoing streams](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/4e56a2f51ad739ca52046723448f3129a58f1666/netwerk/sctp/datachannel/DataChannel.cpp#594) and [2048 incoming streams](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/4e56a2f51ad739ca52046723448f3129a58f1666/netwerk/sctp/datachannel/DataChannel.cpp#595) but allows to renegotiate for up to 2048 streams. However, there is [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1470096) in the renegotiation procedure.

One of the peer takes odd stream IDs and the other takes even stream IDs to create a data channel (which avoids conflicts if both peers create data channels at the same time). The result is that you can create half as many data channels **per peer** as the amount of streams that have been negotiated (minimum of both).

Data channels can also be created in a way where you assign the id yourselves in which case you can create as many data channels as the negotiated amount of streams.

Comment: What's the limit that you've found in rawrtc?

Comment: The limit of what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

software Engineer Lennart Grahl took some tests about maximum RTCDataChannels in chrome and
firefox,so can read about it at this link

https://lgrahl.de/articles/demystifying-webrtc-dc-size-limit.html